# Flowable to Observable in Kotlin with Rx

Tags: observable, rx-java

I should convert the Flowable to Observable and now use this code:

```
return entityDao.getAll()
            .flatMap { list ->
                Flowable.just(list).map {
                    it.map {
                        it.transformToDomain()
                    }
                }
            }
            .toObservable()
```

getAll return the Flowable>.
But I want to change it for this one and it doesn't work:

```
    return wordDao.getAll()
            .flatMap { list ->
              Observable.just(list).map {
                it.map {
                    it.transformToDomain()
                }
            }
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: Could you explain what error do you get? what is the return type of the `getAll()` method?

Comment: getAll() returns Flowable<List<Entity>>

Comment: and the problem when i try to use the second one is ClassCastException

Comment: You can not flatmap a Flowable with an Observable, just look at the flatmap signature and you will see that the types are different. Indeed, ClassCastException means that you are using a type somewhere wrongly.